# Was bedeutet Hubschrauberflug?

Tags: meaning

Ich habe gelesen.

> Wegen technischer Probleme musste Horst Seehofer einen
>   Hubschrauberflug abbrechen

Ich habe in Duden das Wort gesucht aber ich habe nichts gefunden. Was bedeutet Hubschrauberflug?

Comment: Lies es als Hubschrauber-Flug.

Comment: [Hubschrauberflug](https://www.wortbedeutung.info/Hubschrauberflug/)

Comment: Was meinst du hier mit Kontext? - Vielleicht hilft noch dies: *abbrechen* heißt *vorzeitig beenden*.

Comment: Danke @Christian Geiselmann. Ich habe meine Frage geändert

Comment: Hubschrauber = helicopter. Hubbschrauberflug = helicopter flight. Seehofer had to break a helicopter flight.

Comment: Die bemerkenswerte Sache hier ist, dass in der Tat Duden dieses eigentlich recht häufig vorkommende Wort nicht auflistet, weder auf der Website noch z.B. im Duden Universallexikon, 2. Auflage, 1989 (1816 Seiten). - Das Online-Wörterbuch Dict.cc führt es aber auf: https://www.dict.cc/?s=Hubschrauberflug. - Ich nehme das Wort auf in  meine Liste der Wörter, die überraschenderweise nicht im Duden stehen. Es trifft sich dort mit *Tanzknabe*, *ehrenkäsig*, *Bogomilen*, *Knäuzchen* und *Infibulation* - alle fünf deutlich seltener als *Hubschrauberflug*. (Nichtfunde in genannter Duden-Ausgabe.)

Comment: Meaning in context, was sonst. Haha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ein Hubschrauberflug ist ein Flug mit einem Hubschrauber/Helikopter.